# How can I write callback func for setState on event click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback

after onclick event occurs in backpackList.js, fetch data in context.js and then through setState I want to update noneUserCart . After that i want to get data from context.js to backpackList.js to show web page. but the data is inital data []. How can I solve this problem?!
I think this is a Asynchronous problem, but I'm new react, so I don't know how to write code for this. or do I use async, await.
Help me please!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const ProductContext = React.createContext();
const ProductConsumer = ProductContext.Consumer;

class ProductProvider extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      totalProducts: 0,
      isLogin: false,
      cartList: [],
      isNavOpen: false,
      isCartOpen: false,
      noneUserCart: [],
    };
  }
  noneUserAddCart = bagId => {
    fetch('/data/getdata.json', {
      method: 'GET',
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
      .then(data => {
        this.setState(
          {
            noneUserCart: [...this.state.noneUserCart, data],
          },
          () => console.log(this.state.noneUserCart)
        );
      });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <ProductContext.Provider
        value={{
          ...this.state,
          handleCart: this.handleCart,
          getToken: this.getToken,
          addNoneUserCart: this.addNoneUserCart,
          hanldeCheckout: this.hanldeCheckout,
          openNav: this.openNav,
          showCart: this.showCart,
          habdleCartLsit: this.habdleCartLsit,
          deleteCart: this.deleteCart,
          noneUserAddCart: this.noneUserAddCart,
        }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </ProductContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

export { ProductProvider, ProductConsumer };
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ProductConsumer } from '../../context';

export default class BackpackList extends Component {
  render() {
    const {
      backpackdata,
      backdescdata,
      isdescOpen,
      showDesc,
      descClose,
      rangenumone,
      rangenumtwo,
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>      
        {backdescdata.map((bag, inx) => {
          return (
            <>
              {isdescOpen && bag.id > rangenumone && bag.id < rangenumtwo && (
                <div className="listDescContainer" key={inx}>
                  <div className="listDescBox">
                      <ProductConsumer>
                        {value => (
                          <div
                            className="cartBtn"
                            onClick={() => {
                              const token = value.getToken();
                              if (token) {
                                value.handleCart(bag.id, token);
                              } else {
                                value.noneUserAddCart(bag.id);
                                console.log(value.noneUserCart); 
                          // this part. value.noneUserCart is undefined
                              }
                            }}
                          >
                            add to cart.
                          </div>
                        )}
                      </ProductConsumer>

                      <span className="descClosebtn" onClick={descClose}>
                        X
                      </span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              )}
            </>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`fetch` is asynchronous, `this.setState` is yet called when `console.log`

```
         <div
            className="cartBtn"
            onClick={() => {
               const token = value.getToken();
               if (token) {
                 value.handleCart(bag.id, token);
               } else {
                 value.noneUserAddCart(bag.id);
                 console.log(value.noneUserCart); 
                 // this part. value.noneUserCart is undefined
               }
            }}
        >
          add to cart.
          {value.noneUserCart}
          {/* when finished, result should show here */}
        </div>
```